# Pigeonhole principle use

Tags: combinatorics

Let $P(x)$ be a property (not in the strict logical sense, this is only a combinatorial problem).

What is the minimun number of elements that one should have to ensure that one have at least $k$ with the mentioned property?

I think, by the Pignole principle, the answer is $(k-1)n +1$, where $n$ is the number of distinct options for the property to be.

How can one have the solution for the next problem?

Supose that every times one have a set of 8 people, 2 of them have a property $P'$, what is the minimum necessary to ensure that one have 3 people that have that property? 
The answer here is $(8-1)2 + 1 =15$. What is the answer if one wants to have 4 people with this property? What is the answer if one substitutes the original problem with $z$ in place of 8, $x$ in place of 2, $y$ in place of 3 (with the corresponding restrictions)?

How can we attack this problems in general?

Comment: `What is the minimum number of elements that one should have to ensure that one has at least $k$ elements with the mentioned property?` Trivially $k$.

Comment: @GitGud I agree, many users on this page will not bother answering questions like this, made by an OP that shows no interest in accepting or responding to answers.

Comment: sorry, the hypotesis is that, on have n distint options for the property P(x)

Comment: I gave an answer, but I also agree with GitGud and 5xum

Answer (score 0):

The pigeon-hole principle doesn't apply to specific properties.  It states (informally)
If you have k containers, and k+1 objects put into them, there must be at least one container that has 2 objects.

It cannot tell you a minimum number for a certain container to have a particular number of elements without other conditions.  For example, if P(x) was the property of being odd, we could find infinite even numbers not satisfying this property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made confusion between "property" and "function"

Suppose there is a property $P$ so that in every set of $8$ elements, two of them have property $P$.

There are two cases:

1) the universe has less then 8 elements, so it may happen that no element has the property P

2) the universe has at least 8 elements. In this case there are at most 6 elements without property $P$. Indeed given $x_1,\dots,x_6$ without $P$, let  than for any other $x,y$ the set $x_1,\dots,x_6,x,y$ has 8 elements, therefore two of them have $P$. Since $x_i$ have not $P$ it follows that both $x,y$ have $P$. We therefore proved that $\forall x,y\notin\{x_1,\dots,x_6\}$ we have $P(x)$ and $P(y)$.

On the other hand, if $P$ is a function with $n$ possible distinct values, then one can hask about minimum numbers of elements so that we can find $2$ or more with the same value of $P$. Ex: $P(x)\equiv x \pmod{3}$ then the piegon hole principle applies and you see that you need at least $4$ elements to ensure two of them have the same value of $P$.